# SecureCRT could not display some character

Tags: secure-crt

For some reason SecureCRT displays wrong character/coding when I ssh into Linux server.

For example, following is from man route

```
Gateway
              The gateway address or â€™*â€™ if none set.
```

Use a different terminal software (ZOC terminal)

```
Gateway
              The gateway address or ’*’ if none set.
```

ZOC terminal chraacter set is ANSI/Windows/Latin I and I tried that for SecureCRT but did not make any difference.

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with UTF-8 characters and the Linux "locale".

For a modern Linux the command `locale charmap` should normally give you `UTF-8` other values may work but won't give you all the characters eg: ☎ ☐ ☑ ☒

Both of these appear to have the terminal set to `ISO-8859-1` the difference is that ZOC has sent a 'LANG=en_GB' environment variable to the host; SecureCRT has not.

Your best solution is to set your terminal emulator to interpret the `UTF-8` character set then if possible have the emulator send the variable `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8` (or similar) to Linux.

If you can't find how to set the locale in your favourite emulator you can set it after you've logged in

```
$ export LANG=de_AT.UTF-8
```

Obviously you need to choose the correct LANG setting for your location and preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I was still having the issue with SecureCRT despite proper host settings.  Solved it by setting Session Options... -> Terminal -> Appearance -> Character Encoding from "Default" to "UTF-8".

Comment: I believe you need to restart secureCRT to apply the change and it took me a while to figure it out.